# .NET downgrade admin elevation or impersonate as current user when executing specific block of code calling COM+ that requires lower permission

Tags: c#, office-interop, com+, windows-identity

I have a .NET Windows Form application that users run as admin since it requires specific access to files.
The app has been working fine for years but we need to add a feature where users can generate email from inside the application using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
As soon as we call "new" on the Outlook object, it blows up with the following error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving
> the COM class factory for component with CLSID
> {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
> error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

This is because MS Outlook is running without elevated privileges by default and the Windows Form app is running with elevated privileges but COM+ can't handle this setting.

So I need a way to call the .NET Outlook code as the current user but with less elevated privileges.

I have looked at the [WindowsIdentity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity?view=netframework-4.8) Class but it does not seem to work.  I need someway to run a method or block of code as the current user but with less elevated privileges.

Comment: Have you tried [Marshal.GetObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_GetActiveObject_System_String_) instead of new?

Comment: @Steeeve if I try Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") without elevated privileges, it does work but if application is elevated, it throws the following error "Operation unavailable (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))". Looks like GetActiveObject has issues when elevated.

Answer (score 2):

> The app has been working fine for years but we need to add a feature where users can generate email from inside the application using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.

You need to run your WinForms app without admin privileges if you want to automate Outlook in that case. Or just run Outlook under the same security context with your application. Otherwise, you may consider other technologies for sending email - EWS, [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-mail-concept-overview), use the [MailMessage Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage?view=net-5.0) from the .net BCL and etc.

Comment: The desktop app must run as administrator since it requires special permissions to the registry and some of the file system. Also asking all the users to run Outlook as admin is not really an option. I will look into these other 3rd party technologies to see if they might work. I think what I might do is just create a simple console app that wraps the outlook com+ calls and then have my main app call the console app to do the work for me. since the console app is not running as admin, it should work.